# Cakephp 1.3 Deep HABTM find with conditions

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I have the following Models:

`Carrier`,`Store`,`Classification`.

Here is the situation:

`Carrier` **HABTM** `Store` and `Store` **HABTM** `Carrier`.

`Carrier` also **hasMany** `Classification`.

I've been trying for the last 8 hours or so to get all the `Carriers` where `Store.id = 152`.

Where I am having trouble is, I want the resulting array to include `Classification` that are from `Carriers`. I also want to sort by `Classifications` as well. 

I've tried a lot of things. All of my answers have either gotten the right `carriers` without the `classifications` included or gotten **all** the `carriers` with `classifications` included. 

 I've tried containable and it doesn't seem to limit the results, it seems to grab all the carriers and leave stores blank if they aren't the right store. 

I tried joins but I couldn't successfully get that working either. 

I am probably doing something wrong but I can't for the life of me figure it out. 

**with code**

```
class Carrier extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Carrier';
    var $actsAs = array('Containable');
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Rect','Store');
    var $belongsTo = array('Classification','Category');
}

class Store extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Store';
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Carrier');
    var $belongsTo = array('SparkPlug.User');
    var $actsAs = array('Containable');
}

class Classification extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Classification';
    var $actsAs = array('Containable');
    var $hasMany = 'Carrier';
}
```

Comment: Can you paste in the models, within code braces?  I'd be happy to help if I can.

Comment: Added code. Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I have found consists in creating the habtm model and making conditions on that by using contain and a manual joins clause.

The model codes are like this:

`store.php`

```
<?
class Store extends AppModel {

    var $actsAs = array('Containable');
    var $hasMany = array('CarriersStore');
}
?>
```

`carrier.php`

```
<?
class Carrier extends AppModel {

    var $actsAs = array('Containable');
    var $hasMany = array('CarriersStore');
}
?>
```

`carriers_store.php`

```
<?
class CarriersStore extends AppModel {

    var $belongsTo = array('Store', 'Carrier');
    var $actsAs = array('Containable');

}
?>
```

Then, in `carriers_controller.php` the tricky syntax to apply the condition and obtain both Store and Carrier models is:

```
$carriers = $this->Carrier->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('CarrierStore.store_id' => 1),
    'contain' => array('CarriersStore' => array('Store')),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'carriers_stores', 
            'alias' => 'CarrierStore', 
            'type' => 'INNER', 
            'conditions' => array('CarrierStore.carrier_id = Carrier.id')
        )

    )
));
```

I hope this helps. The issue has bugged me for quite a lot of time and only recently have I found this workaround.